# Strange volume issue on Windows 10 I can't solve - across all audio devices (virtual or real)

Tags: windows-10, audio

For a few weeks now, my laptop is randomly alternating between the below two states of this problem:

#### **State 1:**

If I use the system volume keys (i.e., the dedicated volume up/down buttons on my laptop, or FN + Function keys on my USB keyboard), the volume slider appears in the top left, but it doesn't actually change the volume. The number and position of the volume square stays the exact same.

To change volume, I have to click on the sound icon in the notification tray on my taskbar, and then scroll on the volume slider that appears there.

The sound icon in the notification tray accurately reflects this volume.

#### **State 2:**

If I use the system volume keys (i.e., the dedicated volume up/down buttons on my laptop, or FN + Function keys on my USB keyboard), the volume slider appears in the top left. The volume "changes" correctly there, with the number and square going up/down as I press the relevant key, however the real volume I'm hearing does not actually change.

The sound icon in the notification tray reflects this "fake" volume.

However, if I click that sound icon in the notification tray, the volume slider is at a completely different position from what the icon represents.

Only when I scroll on the volume slider that you get from clicking the notification tray, does the real volume I'm hearing actually change.

---

#### **Notes (for both states):**

- I did not make any major system configuration changes before/after this issue started happening
- It happens across all audio devices
- DISM Cleanup Restorehealth + sfc scannow didn't help
- Updated all my audio + chipset drivers, tried reinstalling devices
- Updated BIOS
- Uninstalled all ASUS Bloatware bullshit, especially Armoury Crate with its AI audio stuff, and used G Helper instead
- Ran windows update

All audio devices that I have / had installed:

- External Logitech speakers plugged into mains (3.5mm port)
- Laptop speakers (built into laptop, shows as Realtek audio)
- Two JBL Go 3 External Speakers (Bluetooth)
- Airpods (Bluetooth)
- JVC HA-A10T earphones (Bluetooth)
- AI Noise cancelling output (Asus utility built in drivers)
- Headset Earphone (HyperX Cloud II USB Audio)
- Virtual Audio Input (VB-Audio cable)

I have used all of these at the same time with no issues for around 2 years. The issues started coming up last few weeks.

**I tried unpairing/disconnecting/uninstalling (the drivers of) ALL of these devices except my built in laptop speakers and rebooting multiple times, to no avail**

My system: Asus Zephyrus G15 GA503QM 2021 Gaming Laptop (R7 5800HS + RTX 3060M), Windows 10 22H2 (19045.3693)

This is a really stupid annoying bug that I just can't seem to get to the bottom of. It's barely googleable, even if I use specific wording, and the vaguely relevant pages I did find had no solutions.

All help appreciated